# success":false,"error":"Missing message parameter. Your request may be malformed."}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: message=hello

Tags: http, curl, http-post

```
curl -X POST http://textbelt.com/text \
 --data-urlencode phone=' xx xxxxxxxxxx' \
 --data urlencode message='hello' \     
 -d key=textbelt
```

output

```
{"success":false,"error":"Missing message parameter. Your request may be malformed."}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: message=hello
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear on what the issue is, what's your question?

Comment: `--data urlencode` seems to be missing a dash